# .npm cache vs node_modules size

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When building our node application, we are using .npm cache as follows:

```sh
npm install --cache /tmp/node-cache/.npm --prefer-offline
```

However I have reasons to believe, the cache is not working properly as:

```
/tmp/node-cache/ # du -sh .npm/
177M    .npm/

/tmp/build/ # du -sh node_modules/
1.1G    node_modules
```

Does this mean the build downloaded additional 900 M and not caching them in `.npm` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean the build downloaded additional 900 M and not caching them in .npm directory?

That's possible. But it's also possible that the difference is due to a combination of compression and build artifacts.

The npm cache is compressed. `node_modules` directories are uncompressed.

Furthermore, `npm` almost certainly only caches the source code. If you are using something like `node-sass`, `PhantomJS`, `puppeteer`, or some other thing that has a custom install script or other build step, then build artifacts may balloon your `node_modules`.

I would not necessarily conclude merely from the size difference that the cache is not being respected. You'll have to do more investigation. One thing you might try is:

- Remove `node_modules` (and `package-lock.json` if it exists)
- `npm cache clean --force` and confirm that the cache is very small
- `npm install`
- Check the sizes of `node_modules` and the cache again.